# Is there a way to bypass a firewall?

Tags: firewall

Is there any way to bypassing a firewall?

I've tried using google trans as a temporary solution but it's not what I'm looking for.

Any help is appreciated
thanks

Comment: try ngrok... but you need to identify what route you need

Comment: The question is too broad, if it's your firewall, just turn it off :)

Comment: What OS are you referring to? What type of data are you trying to pass? Is this sudo or admin or system level code?

Comment: @Sparky256 Windows 7. And just normal sites on chrome that are blocked and admin

Comment: Check your Firewall settings, including Advanced settings. Make sure you anti-virus has hardware protect off or set correctly. Make sure DEP is not blocking. Set it to "Opt-In' status. These are just suggestions, not answers guaranteed to work. I have W7 64 bit, and it seems that by default at install time it blocks everything until you tell it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

This is not guaranteed to work, because an anti-virus program and DEP can block as well. You have to 'teach' your PC what to block and what to accept. This can take some time. For now: Go to your Start button and type in FIREWALL. You should see an option pop-up: Windows Firewall with Advanced Security. Select the 'Firewall' from it's options. Look for Google Chrome\path\chrome.exe on the list and make sure that under the column labeled 'Action' it is set to 'Allow'. If not you will have to click on the entry and select 'Properties'